# Export data flow to csv file in Sftp server

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to make some logic for data from diffrents data sources  after that I want to generate csv file with the result of joins and save it in a Sftp server.

I made a data flow that contains my logic, joins and conditions,after that when I sink data to Sftp dataset an error is appearing
[image]

is there any solutions to make this ? making join from different table in different database and export a csv file to sftp server and in the same time using Azure data factory for this.
Thanks.

Comment: Like the error said, SFTP is not supported in Data Flow. You can ref the connector support overview: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview. We can't change this. May be you could store the file into blob storage first and then copy it to SFTP.

Comment: @LeonYue thank you for reponse, is there any other solution without passing by the blob ?

Comment: No, unfortunately, you will have to stage this either in blob/lake or a SQL sink before you ship it to the SFTP destination.

Comment: @RaunakJhawar so no solution ? Even with dataset in activity  to make some joins and export to sftp directly without stage data to another source !

Comment: Hi @Houssem I'm afraid to say there isn't a solution for now.

Comment: @Houssem May I post it as answer?

Comment: yes please. (therefore for information i will be try to use temporary table in SQL so I can then copy data from one dataset to sftp server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the error said, SFTP is not supported in Data Flow. You can ref the connector [support overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-overview). We can't change this.

Some workarounds are that you could store the file into a temp storage firstly, like blob storage or table in SQL database, then copy the data into SFTP again.

I'm glad you will try to use temporary table in SQL and then copy data from one dataset to SFTP server.

HTH.